# Motioneye 'Mass Storage' Option Doesn't Exit

Tags: motioneyeos

I have installed the Motioneye on my local Ubuntu server PC by following the instructions on the wiki. I am following the instructions at [this link](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/cctv-raspberry-pi-based-system-storage-motioneyeos/)

On my PC, I have two different physical disks. One is a 256GB Sata SSD, the other is a 4 TB regular Sata HDD. I have formatted my HDD based on [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive) and I mount my HDD at /storage/disk1 and
I believe that I format the disk correctly and mount it correctly.

But still, I can not see the mass storage option on the web GUI

[image]

When I run the command `df -h` I get:

[image]

What do you think I should do?

Comment: I wanted to make some editorial changes but I couldn't find how I can do it and @marc_s I tried to send you pm to thank you for changing the question in a better way but I couldn't find it either. Thank you